# Как "вытащить" переменную из функции в Python

Tags: python, функции

```
def example():
   box = 15


print(box)
```

> Вопрос заключается в том, как получить значение переменной вне функции.
>
> > Данный код выдаёт ошибку: NameError: name 'box' is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам это нужно, значит вы что-то делаете не так. Стандартный подход заключается в том, чтобы функция возвращала вам результат своей работы:

```py
def example():
   box = 15
   case = 25
   return box, case


box, case = example()
print(box, case)
```

---

Но ради спортивного интереса, есть возможность сохранить некоторое значение в параметрах самой функции:

```py
def example():
    example.box = 15


example()
print(example.box)
```

Answer (score 1):

Допустим так:

```
def example():
    box = 15
    return box

print(example())
```

Или так:

```
def example():
    box = 15
    return box

boxNew = example()
print(boxNew)
```

Comment: Это так же будет работать и с 2,3 переменными в функции? 
То есть если у меня в функции будут переменные - box,box1,box2,box3, будет ли работать такая же аналогия как и в приведённом вами выше примере?

Comment: Вот что я имел ввиду:
Ссылка на имгур: https://imgur.com/a/N5xzuA1

Comment: Все зависит от того, как эти переменные будут передаваться в функцию(и будут ли вообще)